# How to return a string with no overhead inside helper function

Tags: c++

I want to put this logic into a helper function:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string str = "some str";
if (do_check(str)) {
  ss << str;
} else {
  ss << do_edit(str);
}
```

and instead write it like

```
std::string edit_str(const std::string &str) {
  if (do_check(str)) {
    return str;
  }
  
  return do_edit(str);
}

main() {
  std::stringstream ss;
  std::string str = "some str";
  ss << edit_str(str);
}
```

However, this creates a copy when I return str. Is there any way to write this as a helper function with no/minimal overhead? I'm open to changing the parameter/return type, using output parameters, templates, etc., but I would like to avoid using macros.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to modify the `str` variable of `main`? Or, you want to leave the original untouched, and return a modified copy? You can't (easily) have both, either you modify the original or you return a copy (modified or not).

Comment: Why not have the function take the stream and the string?  Then you could have something like `add_edited_str_to_stream(ss, str);`

Comment: @hyde I think I'm asking for both to happen here, so maybe it's not possible. do_edit will return a modified copy and ideally the original should be untouched.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that would work, and answers this specific question. Ideally though, I was imagining something that could work even if I wasn't using a string stream, like assigning another string variable to the returned value.

Comment: @tenkay There *is* a concept called "copy-on-write", which is sounds nice: a container keeps reference count of how many variables share the same data, and if one of these variables sharing the data is modified, it first takes copy of the data (original reference count decremented, new copy has reference count 1 so can be modified in-place). For example Qt framework's `QString` uses this. However, especially on modern computers, overhead of copy-on-write is almost always more than the overhead of sometimes taking unnecessary copy (when can't pass reference or move).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library sets the standard for how to do this with functions like `std::quoted`. The function actually does no work; it just stores references to the arguments into an object, called the IO manipulator. Then the `operator<<` for that object is what does the actual work. We can simply follow their example.

```
struct edited { // playing a little fast-and-loose; instead of a dedicated function we just aggregate-initialize this struct with a function-like syntax (requires C++20)
    std::string const &str;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, edited const &thiz) {
        // you can put whatever block of code you'd like to factor out in here
        if (do_check(thiz.str)) out << thiz.str;
        else out << do_edit(thiz.str);
        return out;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::string str = "some string";
    std::cout << edited(str);
}
```

You do have to be careful not to accidentally use `edited(str)` like a string. The only thing you should be doing with it is `<<`ing it into a stream. If you need a `std::string` from it at some point, make a `std::stringstream` and use that to collect the output. Also, it may be beneficial to inline `do_edit` into `operator<<` and adjust it so it does not return an intermediate string that then gets output but can just output directly, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom type that has an overload for `<<`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

bool do_check(const std::string&) {return false;}
void do_edit(std::string& in){
    in = "foo";
}

struct checked_string {
    std::string& value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const checked_string& cs) {
    if (! do_check(cs.value)) {
        do_edit(cs.value);
    }
    out << cs.value;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "some str";
    std::cout << checked_string{str};
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you think `do_edit` modifies its argument? It doesn't seem like it does in the OP's code. The OP is not primarily worried about copying from `do_edit`, just copying when *not* performing `do_edit`.

Comment: @HTWN oh right, completely misread the code